# OpenERP - call method after creating record?

Tags: python, odoo, overloading

How could I call my method just after creation of record was made. So far:

```
def _compute_stage_deadline(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    for lead in self.browse(cr, uid, ids):

        stage_deadline = datetime.now() + lead.stage_id.days_for_stage
        print "Testing stage datetime: ", stage_deadline.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    return stage_deadline   

def create(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    self._compute_stage_deadline(cr, uid, ids, context)
    return super(CRM_Lead, self).create(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
```

But there I call it just before creating record, so when in `_compute_stage_deadline` I try to access that record I get this error (because that record does not exist yet):

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'stage_id'
```

How could I bypass it and call my method just after creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this problem using this approach:

```
def _compute_stage_deadline(self, cr, uid, lead, context=None):        
    stage_deadline = datetime.now() + lead.stage_id.days_for_stage
    print "Testing stage datetime: ", stage_deadline.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    return stage_deadline   

def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
    new_id = super(CRM_Lead, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
    lead = self.browse(cr, uid, new_id, context=context)
    self._compute_stage_deadline(cr, uid, lead, context)
    return new_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Use vals instead of lead:

```
def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
 self._compute_stage_deadline(cr, uid, vals, context)
 return super(CRM_Lead, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
```